# How to use BNF for {a^n b^n | n>0}

Tags: regular-languages

so I know that this language is not regular, however, can you still define the language using BNF? This is the problem:

```
{a^n b^n |n>0}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of a context-free language.  See [How to prove that a language is context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755) for how to find the corresponding context-free grammar.  Then once you have a context-free grammar, you can write it down in [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form).